# Current Vs Last Year SSRS Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I am new in SSRS Reporting, I face a problem in sales report.I want to do a report like this

**Team**   **Current**   **Last**

**A**                             **1000**             **200**

**B**                              **2000**           **6000**

How can I do this in expression

Answer (score 0):

First from query get all records for current & last year like Team,Sale,Year and then at report level do column grouping at Table and Group On Year, then include column that you want to display in your Report.

Comment: If I use column grouping , i will divide the year into column ..It is right for 2 years but I have data upto 2000 to 2012. So I use filter to select the year.So what can i do next..

Comment: Yes, you can the use grouping filter